# Combinatorics/Counting Puzzle

Tags: combinatorics

The monks in a Vietnamese monastery have a daily ritual: placing rings on 6 sticks in the garden. A maximum of 2 rings can be on a stick at once, and the total number of rings must be **even**. For how many days can the monks perform their ritual without repeating themselves? (In other words, how many different configurations are there? 0 rings is also a configuration.) You can view an illustrated configuration below.

[image]

Even though I have a rough estimate of the answer, I'd like to know what formulae/rules could be used in solving this problem. The only way known to me at the moment is to brute force it and count each configuration. Thanks in advance!

Edit: changed 'sticks' to 'rings'.

Comment: "and the total number of sticks must be even."  Well, you just said the number of sticks is $6$" and I'm not aware of any cases where $6$ is *not* even....

Comment: Yup, my bad. Will correct the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean "the number of $\textit {rings}$ must be even".

Let $a_n$ be the number, given $n$ sticks.  The answer you want is $a_6$.

For symmetry's sake, let $b_n$ be the number of configurations such that the total number of rings is odd.

Since there are $3$ choices per stick we see that $$a_n+b_n=3^n$$

It is easy to see that $a_1=2, b_1=1$.  It is also clear that $$a_n=2a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}=3^{n-1}+a_{n-1}\quad \&\quad b_n=a_{n-1}+2b_{n-1}=3^{n-1}+b_{n-1}$$
(for $a_n$: if the first $n-1$ terms belong to $a_{n-1}$ you have two ways to complete the pattern, while if the first $n-1$ terms belong to $b_{n-1}$ there is only one way.  And similarly for $b_n$).

We then quickly deduce that $$\boxed {a_6=365}$$ so they can keep going for exactly one year.

Note:  it's not too difficult to deduce from the above that $$a_n=\frac {3^n+1}2\quad \&\quad b_n=\frac {3^n-1}2$$

Comment: You're right, I meant the number of rings, my bad. Thank you for the very simple, but complete answer! If you don't mind, could you please explain how you found that $a_n=\frac {3^n+1}2$ ?

Comment: Once one spots the pattern there is no difficulty in proving it by induction.  To spot it...well, for large $n$ you have to figure that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are roughly equal, so you figure the answer is around $\frac 12\times 3^n$ for both.

Comment: Note:  there's probably a clear combinatorial reason why $b_n=a_n-1$, but I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I have to say your problem solving skills are very good. I wish I could see these patterns as quickly as you do.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on spotting things, note that $a_n=2+3+3^2+\cdots +3^{n-1}$ and use Geometric Series to sum the powers of $3$.

Comment: Although I think I understand what you mean, for me this answer is equally as hard to find as the original one you posted. I guess I should just practice some more to spot stuff like this more easily, both the geometric sum and the first equation you gave. Thank you for being so helpful, if you're interested in seeing more of these problems, definitely let me know! I still have a few of them that I don't quite understand.

Comment: Yes, the best way to learn how to recognize patterns is to work lots and lots of examples.  No question about it.

Answer (score 1):

If we remove the restriction that the total number of rings is odd, we can note that each ring can have $0,1,2$ rings so there $3^6$ total ways to place the rings.

Can not that if we arrange the rings so that ring #$i$ has $k_i$ rings an it that we each combination $(k_1,k_2, k_3, k_4, k_5, k_6)$ coresponds to exactly one number $3^5 k_6 + 3^4k_5 + 3^3k_4 + 3^2k_3 + 3k_2 + k_1$ (we can think of this as a number written in trinary).

Now of the $3^6=729$ numbers from $0... 728$ that $365$ of them, $0,2,4,.....,724,726,728$ are even and $364$ of them $1,3,5,...,75,727$  are odd.

But we aren't interested in whether the number is odd or even but whether the sum of the digits is odd or even.

Well the number is $\sum_{i=0}^6 k_i*3^i$ and the sum of the digits is $\sum_{i=0}^6 k_1$ and so the difference between the number and the sum of its digits is $\sum_{i=0}^6 (3^i-1)k_i$.  And as $(3^i -1)$ is an even  number is odd or even if and only if the sum of it's tertiary digits is odd or even.  (THis is equivalent to the base $10$ rule of a number being divisible by $9$ if and only if the some of its digits are divisible by $9$; for exactly the same reason.)

So there are $365$ ways to do this.

===== alternative====

Suppose you have $k$ sticks with $0$ rings, $m$ sticks with one ring and and $z$ sticks with $2$ rings.  So the total number of rings you have is $m + 2z$.

That must be an even number so $m$ must be even so you can only have an even number of sticks with $1$ ring on it.  So the number of sticks with $1$ ring is $m=0, 2,4,6$.

Now then number of ways you can choose which $m$ sticks to be odd is ${6\choose m}$ ways.

There are $6-m$ remaining sticks.  Those can each have either $0$ or $2$ rings.  So there are $2^{6-m}$ way's those $6-m$ sticks can have rings.

So if you have $m$ sticks with $1$ ring there are ${6\choose m}2^{6-m}$ ways to do that.

So if $m =0$ and you can't have any sticks with $1$ ring then the remaining $6$ sticks may have $0$ or $2$ rings so there are $2^6$ ways or ${6\choose 0}2^{6-0}$ ways to do this with no sticks having $1$ ring.

If $m=2$ and there are eactly two sticks with $1$ ring then there are ${6\choose 2}= \frac {6!}{2!4!}=\frac {5*6}2=15$ ways to choose those two rings. The remaining $4$ rings can have $0$ or $2$ rings so there are $2^{4}$ ways for a total of $15*2^4= {6\choose 2}2^{6-2}$ ways to do this.

And so on.....

Total number of ways is ${6\choose 0}2^{6} + {6\choose 2}2^{4} + {6\choose 4}2^2 + {6\choose 6}2^0 =$

$1*64 + 15*16 + 15*4 + 1*1=$

$64 + 15(16+4) + 1=$

$64 + 300 + 1 = 365$ or

One for each day of the year!